# Entity Framework and Guid

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, guid

let's say I have this code :

```
var foo = new Foo { Id = Guid.NewGuid(); }

var id = foo.Id; // have access to the id here

context.Add(foo);
context.SaveChanges();
```

How does `Guid.NewGuid()` avoid collision with a Guid already on my Database? What if the generated guid already exists on the database ? I don't get it.

Using a autoincrement id is obvious, but I won't know the id until I save to the database which make sense. How does guid does it to work 'different' ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How does Guid.NewGuid() avoid collision with a Guid already on my
>   Database?

If doesn't. You just have different ids generated each time. Actually chance of generating equal Guids is [very low](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> What if the generated guid already exists on the database?

If you will provide same Guid value, you will have violation of primary key constraint. Following code will produce *Cannot insert duplicate key* error

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
context.Foos.Add(new Foo { Id = guid });
context.Foos.Add(new Foo { Id = guid });
context.SaveChanges();
```

NOTE: You can ask Entity Framework to generate guid key on database side for you. Use [DatabaseGenerated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.databasegeneratedattribute.databasegeneratedattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute for that:

```
public class Foo
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now just save Foo without generating key manually, and EF will update id with guid generated by database:

```
var foo = new Foo { Value = 42 };
context.Foos.Add(foo); // id is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
context.SaveChanges();     
// now id has value generated during insert 421ffa94-1970-e311-9e31-001fd09468de
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm yet to see any benefit of guid over int on PK.

Comment: @Bart well, guid gives you uniqueness of keys. That is really good when you have to merge data from different databases. But usually I prefer int or long PK due to readability of such keys

Comment: Thanks for this! If you're using the EF designer, you can get this behavior by setting the StoreGeneratedPattern property to Identity for the Guid.

Comment: For Code First, `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)` works fine on the property definition.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**, there is a very low probability that it could be duplicated.

**Remarks Section:**

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all
>   computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such
>   an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

If Id is a `Unique/Primary Key` of your Foo table, it will throw an error in case if it is duplicated.